# Angular: transmitir data entre componentes (de un hijo al padre, y de este a un componente "nieto")

Tags: angular, eventos, input, componentes, compartir-información

Soy nuevo en Angular y tengo una consulta sobre la **comunicacion** entre componentes. Resulta que desde un componente **"child"** le estoy enviando un dato **"boolean"** a un **"parent"** para que estos se los transmita al resto de sus "child" (el boolean es basicamente para poder realizar distintos *ngclass en los componentes para cambiar sus estilos, al hacer click en un button dentro del hijo, tanto el padre como otros componentes cambian sus estilos). Para esto estoy utilizando el metodo de los **@Output, EventEmitter y los @Input** para compartir informacion.

No tengo problemas en realizarlo entre los hijos directos del padre, pero tengo **el caso de varios componentes con otros componentes hijos dentro**, y son justamente en algunos de estos componentes **"nietos"** donde quiero cambiar los estilos al hacer click en el button, y aparentemente **no puedo lograr que les llege el dato enviado el button, y no modifican sus clases**.

**¿Puedo hacer que a estos componentes "nietos" les llegue ese dato boolean usando esta metodologia de Output e Input, o si o si estoy obligado a usar otro metodo como un Service?** (estoy al tanto de que este ultimo es mas recomendable, pero me interesa saber si lo puedo resolver de la primera manera)

Saludos a todos!!

Comment: En ese caso un servicio es lo más práctico.

Comment: Claro, si, entiendo que usar un Service es la mejor opcion, pero esto interesado en saber si hay manera de poder hacer que a este componente "nieto" le llegue el dato que se le esta transmitiendo al "abuelo" de otro de sus componentes "hijos", o si si o si deberia usar un service para lograr esta comunicacion. Gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: Hola, varias cosas: 1. Comparte codigo aunque sea de ejemplo 2. El concepto padre-hijo es estandar, si tienes un nieto, ese es el hijo de alguien y ese padre siempre podra pasar por input/output mediante emitters los valores... de padre a hijo, de padtre a hijo y asi hasta el infinito...... el problema esta en que ese modelo de codigo es insostenible a futuro, es mejor un servicio en el que creas un subject y  te cuelgas con observables desde los componentes